# Required POST parameter in django or django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

How do you enforce a required field when using POST in django view or django-rest-framework view other than this:

```
required_field = ['id', 'email', 'name']
for f in required_field:
    if not f in request.POST:
        print "Required field missing"
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django REST Framework allows you to specify [`required=True`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required) when initializing the field. If you are using a model, Django REST Framework will automatically detect if the field is required based on if the field has `empty=False` specified when it was initialized.

When working outside of Django REST Framework, there is no better way of checking for required fields than doing what you are currently doing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using [advanced-serializer-usage](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage) to dynamically declare which field is used. In that case how can I set the required option to true?

Comment: By default, fields are set to `required=True`. If you are dynamically removing fields, it shouldn't make a difference. You can change whether or not a field is required on the fly by changing the `required` property on the field, but I would avoid doing this unless you are doing it in a thread-safe way.

Comment: any updates in 2018 ? Can we set up required fields in our custom API endpoints?